# How do I rebind the mvc model for a bootstrap modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 application containing a grid with a link button to trigger the display of record details. I'm using a bootstrap modal dialog to display record details when the user selects a grid row.

I don't want to load the record details unless they are asked for; there are too many data elements involved (1000+).

The grid page uses a modal div containing the partial page (with a ViewModel reference).

I need the partial page's ViewModel to refresh prior to the display of the dialog. so when the user clicks the link, I get the record id from the grid and use it to create the url to the controller method - which seems to work, but seems to happen AFTER the dialog is shown.

How do I get this to work?
This code is in my Index.cshtml:
    
        
            
                
                    ×
                    Account Number: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber)

@{Html.RenderPartial("_KeyTable");}
                        @{Html.RenderPartial("_LoanTable");}

Close

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divDialog").hide();

    $("#btnClose").hide();
    $("#lblAcceptAll").show();
    $("#OnHoldsGrid").focus();

    pageGrids.OnHoldsGrid.onRowSelect(function (e) {
        accountNumber = e.row.AccountNumber;
    });

    $(".modal-link").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#detailsModal').removeData("modal");
        var url = '@(Url.Action("_DetailsForModal", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?accountNumber=' + accountNumber;
        $('#detailsModal').load(url);
        $('#detailsModal').modal('show');
        //alert(url);
    });
});

// This code is in my Controller:
public ActionResult _DetailsForModal(string accountNumber)
{   // This refreshes the data in the ViewModel:
    LOIHoldsViewModel model = new LOIHoldsViewModel();
    model.GetLOIHoldExtended(accountNumber);
    return PartialView("_DetailsForModal", model);
}

// This code is in my partial page _KeyTable.cshtml:
@model LOIHolds.Models.LOIHoldsViewModel
<div id="divKeyTable">
    <br />
    <hr />
    <div class="KeyTableExpandContent">
        <h2><a href="#">Show/Hide Key Table Information</a></h2>
    </div>

    <label>Provider Date:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LOIHoldWithTables.KeyTable.ProviderDate)
    <label>PFI Date:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LOIHoldWithTables.KeyTable.PFIDate)
    <label>User Accept Date:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LOIHoldWithTables.KeyTable.UserAcceptDate)
    <label>User Deny Date:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LOIHoldWithTables.KeyTable.UserDenyDate)
    <label>Process Date:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LOIHoldWithTables.KeyTable.ProcessDate)
    <label>Fiserv Accept Date:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LOIHoldWithTables.KeyTable.FiservAcceptDate)
</div>

<script>
    $('.KeyTableExpandContent').click(function () {
        $('.divKeyTable').toggle();
    });
</script>

// This is the partial _DetailsForModal.cshtml:
@model LOIHolds.Models.LOIHoldsViewModel

<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="detailsModalLabel"><label>Account Number: </label>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber) </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("_KeyTable");}
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("_LoanTable");}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="CancelModal" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Ajax when you click the .modal-link:

```
$(".modal-link").click(function (event) {

var mUrl = '@(Url.Action("DetailsForModal", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?accountNumber=' + accountNumber;

   $.ajax({
    url: mUrl,
    success:function(result){
         // result should contain PartialView from Controller
        //Assign Modal DIV the PartialView
         $('#detailsModal').html(result);
         $('#detailsModal').modal('show');
         }
});
}
```

Put your Modal Logic in a Partial View, then Create a function in Home Controller: Something like this:

```
  public ActionResult DetailsForModal(int accountNumber){

var model = new PartialModalDialogViewModel();
    //   Load Modal  Data

     return PartialView("PartialViewName", model);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Try removing this from the Modal Partial View and put in somewhere in the `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="detailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Comment: Dawood Awan, Thank you for the quick reply and the advice. I have implemented your suggestion and while there's no error thrown and the screen background fade happens, the pop-up box does not ever appear. Would you have any idea why that's happening?

Comment: I don't actually know what your error is as I haven't seen your code, but see the Edit in my Answer

Comment: I used an alert(result); to show me the returned value and the new values ARE in place! KUDOES to you! Now, if I can just get this popup to display...

Comment: It would help if you post your new PartialView Code in Question

Comment: I've just updated the question to be clearer with what code is where - Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No, after moving the "detailsModal" div to the _Layout.cshtml there was no difference at all.